# MS Graph authentication issue

Tags: php, microsoft-graph-api

My company has a WordPress-based intranet and we use Office365. I am hoping to hook into the graph as a global application (without explicit user consent) to grab data. I've gotten all of it working, but am having trouble with the /users/user_name/calendarview endpoint.

I can get valid access tokens using the following:

```
$auth_request_body = http_build_query( array(
    'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
    'client_id' => CLIENT_ID,
    'client_secret' => SECRET_KEY,
    'resource' => 'https://graph.microsoft.com/'
) );

$response = wp_remote_post( $url, array(
    'body' => $auth_request_body
) );

$body = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ) );

$token_type = $body->token_type;
$access_token = $body->access_token;
```

and can make several successful calls, for example to the `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1/users/user_name` endpoint or to the `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1/groups/group_id` endpoint, however when attempting to reach the `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1/users/user_id/calendarview` endpoint I get the following response:

```
[body] => {
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorAccessDenied",
        "message": "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": request_id,
            "date": "2018-08-08T21:57:50"
        }
     }
 }
 [response] => Array
    (
        [code] => 403
        [message] => Forbidden
    )
```

I am working on my local environment, and for testing purposes I have granted all application / delegated permissions to my local machine (I think .. I'm still not positive how to ensure that newly grated permissions take effect on my local machine).

Any thoughts here?

Answer (score 0):

... Nevermind.

Apparently my newly delegated permissions simply hadn't taken effect yet. This method above DOES work for my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should confirm whether to grant the appropriate permissions to the application.[image]